# Get item value from the list view without calling onItemClickListner

Tags: java, android

**What i want to do:** 
I want to get all the `List View` items and send it to the other activity 
or getting `List View` item without declaring o`nItemClickListner` when I get the list items I want them to store into the other list and send that list to other activity where I can fetch all the items from the list

**Question**
How to fetch values of single list view item contain multiple fields i.e edit text

**What i am Doing**

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.save_information){

            list = new ArrayList();

            for (int i =0 ; i < arrayAdapter.getCount() ; i++){

                Language_data_comes_here l = arrayAdapter.getItem(i);
                list.add(l);

            }



            Intent i = new Intent (Language_Activity.this , Selecting_Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("List" , list);
            startActivity(i);

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**Language Activity**

```
   package com.example.wildstone.cv_maker;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Language_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView ;
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton ;
    Custom_Adapter_for_Language arrayAdapter ;
    ArrayList<Language_data_comes_here> arr ;
    Toolbar toolbar ;
    String language_1 = null ;
    ArrayList list ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_language_);

        Toolbar toolbar1 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_custom);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar1);

        floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button);
        floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.plus);
        floatingActionButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        arr = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayAdapter = new Custom_Adapter_for_Language(Language_Activity.this , arr);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Language_Activity.this);
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater() ;

                View view  = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.enter_language , null);
                final EditText language = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.language_entered);

                toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

                toolbar.setTitle("  Add Language !");
                toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.language);

                Button add_language = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.enter_language);

                add_language.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        arr.add(new Language_data_comes_here( R.mipmap.language , language.getText().toString()));


                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        builder.setCancelable(true);
                        language.setText("");

                        getListCount();
                    }
                });

                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setView(view);

                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create() ;
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                arr.remove(position);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                getListCount();
                return false;
            }
        }) ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.button_for_toolbar, menu);
        return true ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.save_information){

            list = new ArrayList();

            for (int i =0 ; i < arrayAdapter.getCount() ; i++){

                Language_data_comes_here l = arrayAdapter.getItem(i);
                list.add(l);

            }

            Intent i = new Intent (Language_Activity.this , Selecting_Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("List" , list);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder  = new AlertDialog.Builder(Language_Activity.this);

        builder.setTitle("Attention !");
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setMessage("Please Click on the SAVE button at the top right corner ! ");
        builder.setPositiveButton("close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create() ;
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void getListCount () {

        int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b);
        t.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    }

    public void gettingListViewElements () {

        int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();

        switch (count){

            case 1 :

                Language_data_comes_here getValue = arr.get(0);
                String getFirstValue = String.valueOf(getValue);

                break ;
            case 2 :
                break ;
            case 3 :
                break ;
            case 4 :
                break ;
            case 5 :
                break ;
            case 6 :
                break ;
            case 7 :
                break ;
            case 8 :
                break ;
            case 9 :
                break ;
            case 10 :
                break ;

            default:
                break ;
        }    
    }


    private void getting_data_from_fields_and_sending_on_click_listner() {
        gettingListViewElements();
    }

}
```

**Language Adapter Activity**

```
package com.example.wildstone.cv_maker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Custom_Adapter_for_Language extends ArrayAdapter<Language_data_comes_here>
{
    Context context ;;

    public Custom_Adapter_for_Language(Context context, ArrayList<Language_data_comes_here> array) {
        super(context,0 , array);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView ;

        if (v == null){

            v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view ,parent ,false);

        }

        Language_data_comes_here language_data_comes_here = getItem(position);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_image_display_list_item);
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_text_display_list_item);

        textView.setText(language_data_comes_here.getLanguage());
        imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.language);

return v ;
    }
}
```

**Language Data**

```
package com.example.wildstone.cv_maker;

/**
 * Created by wildstone on 08/02/2018.
 */

public class Language_data_comes_here {

    private String data ;
    private int image ;

    Language_data_comes_here(int image , String data){

        this.data = data ;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are heading down a bad path here unless I misunderstand your question. You are trying to avoid maintaining the list? If you avoid maintaining the list you can always expose the getData method from your adapter to give it back, but I'm not sure why you are not just retaining the list that you are using to populate the list to begin with

Comment: Actually i am building app that require info from the user .. User add languages in language activity when he click on save button i want that all the language that user enter into the list and send that list to the main activity where i use that knowledge and build a pdf

Comment: But everytime they add a language you are creating the model that is being added to the list, so you already have the list. Do you get what I'm saying?

Comment: yup need to declare  list = new ArrayList(); somewhere else ... but i am saying how can i get all the list view item values (that where i stuck)

Comment: Wrong way. Its not about the items in an item in the listview. All your data is hold in your array adapter in one or more array lists. So thats the place to extract it from.

Comment: it felt like i am getting something to solve the problem thanks @greenapps

Comment: i ll look into it

Comment: I don't understand what to do in adapter class to get the value of list item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow i solved the problem by

```
    Language_data_comes_here d = (Language_data_comes_here) listView.getAdapter().getItem(0);
```